# Extras zeroes getting appended during round to two decimal point in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, procedure

I am writing a postgres procedure. In that I want to round a floating point number to two decimal point and then insert that into a table. I have written the below code.

```
vara float8;
SELECT round( float8 '3.1415927', 2 ) into vara;
insert into dummyTable(columnA)values(vara).
```

I want the columnA to contain the value 3.14. However the value which is getting inserted is 3.1400.

The data type of columnA is float8 with precision and scale 17.

Comment: The column data type decides!

Comment: @jarlh can you be more specific

Comment: The column data type decides the format. (Not the INSERT, or the ROUND.)

Answer (score 3):

There is only one function `round` with two arguments, and that takes `numeric` as argument:

```
test=> \df round
                         List of functions
   Schema   | Name  | Result data type | Argument data types | Type 
------------+-------+------------------+---------------------+------
 pg_catalog | round | double precision | double precision    | func
 pg_catalog | round | numeric          | numeric             | func
 pg_catalog | round | numeric          | numeric, integer    | func
(3 rows)
```

So what happens is that your `float8` is converted to `numeric` (without scale), and the result is of the same type. This will *not* produce trailing zeros:

```
test=> SELECT round(3.14159265, 2);
 round 
-------
  3.14
(1 row)
```

But if you store the result in a `float8` column, you may get rounding errors:

```
test=> SET extra_float_digits = 3;
SET
test=> SELECT round(3.14159265, 2)::float8;
        round        
---------------------
 3.14000000000000012
(1 row)
```

My recommendation is to use `numeric(10,2)` or something similar as the data type of the table column, then the rounding will happen automatically, and the value can never have more than two decimal places.